# Mixed Content Error when migrating from http to https

Tags: html, https

I recently converted my website over to https via cloudflare and I have experienced an error when trying to load my external html header and footer via w3 school's html include. The error is this

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://multicrew.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://multicrew.co.uk/indexheader'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

And my html include code is this

```
<!-- Header -->
    <div w3-include-html="indexheader.html"></div>
```

With this within the  tag

```
<!-- Header/Footer Import Script -->
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your `indexheader.html` file may have references to your `http` links in there somewhere.

Comment: Nope they are the https links

Comment: I only have 2 external links which both have been changed to the https counterparts

Comment: Possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801184/https-request-with-xmlhttprequest